# What is this particular piece of a GUI called?

Tags: gui-design, ui-element

What is the dividing line between the directory tree and the right-side view called?  Specifically, what is the name of the "grab it and slide/resize" function?  I'm trying to make this in wxPython but I don't know the name of it.

[image]

Comment: try `SplitterWindow`

Comment: @DavidA - thanks, thats exactly what I was trying to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes by a few different names, but the most widely accepted name is "**Splitter**"

[Example 1](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/splitter/index)

[Example 2](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/expandablesplitter.aspx)

[Example 3](http://www.igniteui.com/help/igsplitter-overview)

[Example 4](http://docs.componentart.com/default.aspx?content=UIFramework/2011/ComponentArt.Web.UI.AJAX/Splitter_Creating_a_Basic_Splitter_Layout.htm)

[Example 5](http://www.infragistics.com/samples/windows-forms/splitter/overview)

[Example 6](http://wijmo.com/widgets/wijmo-open/splitter/)

Answer (score 3):

**If you're looking for an interaction pattern name:**
It's just a column or pane divider. Whether or not it's resizable is up to you.
The general arrangement is a sort of modified [Miller Column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns) or [master detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%E2%80%93detail_interface) UI.

**If you're looking for the code function to call:**
You came to the wrong SE site.

Comment: Not looking for code, just trying to figure out what exactly to search for.